# Detecting computer name

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, comparison, hostname

How can I detect if I am on a certain host computer in a batch script? Ex if I run the command `hostname` it gives me the current computers hostname. Is there a way that I can save that to a variable or directly compare it to something else?

```
set hostnameVar=hostname`
if "%hostnameVar%" == "Molly-Laptop" (Echo laptop)
```

or

```
if hostname == "Molly-Potato" (Echo notlaptop)
```

Neither of these are working.

Comment: Is what you posted what you have actually attempted?  Are you against using a Power Shell script instead?

Comment: I'm open to a powershell script.

Comment: In the mean time I've also found that both computers have an environment variable of `COMPUTERNAME`

So with `set tempVar=Molly-Laptop` and `if %COMPUTERNAME% EQU %tempVAR% (Echo laptop)` Its working. Is this COMPUTERNAME variable fairly standard? and reasonable to expect?

Comment: Its a environment variable, its reasonable to expect it to be there, unless you remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, you can use `%computername%`.  This is a [standard Windows environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) provided exactly for why you want to use it.

Additionally, and to more directly answer your question:

`set hostnameVar=hostname` doesn't work because that's assigning the name of the program itself to the variable -- not its result.

So after you typed the above in a command prompt, if you then typed `%hostnameVar%` it would act just like you typed/ran `hostname` (and give you a result).

This is also why your 2nd `if` doesn't work --  you're essentially saying `If ("hostname") == ("this text string")`.  Since the text string doesn't match the name of the program, it will fail.

Having said all that, you *can* redirect output of a command to a variable in batch by using a FOR loop:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('hostname') do set output=%%i
if "%output%" == "Molly-Laptop" (Echo laptop)
```

Comment: covered on all fronts @techie007 awesome answer as usual

Comment: @PsychoData Turns out I was giving the batch variables too much credit. They can't store a reference to the program, it just stores the name.  Updated answer to reflect that. :)

Comment: well, is i said `set hostnameVar=hostname` and then typed %hostnameVar% it returns hostname and executes hostname

Answer (score 1):

This seems overly complex to have to set a variable that exists as an environmental variable.

Please see my suggested comments as I'm sure you've resolved your issue, this is just a better way to write it for anyone looking towards to future.

```
IF "%COMPUTERNAME%" EQU "MOLLY-LAPTOP" ECHO Laptop
IF "%COMPUTERNAME%" EQU "MOLLY-POTATO" ECHO Not Laptop
```

Or...

```
IF "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="MOLLY-LAPTOP" ECHO Laptop
IF "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="MOLLY-POTATO" ECHO Not Laptop
```

I don't like the secondary statement so I would follow this.

```
IF NOT "%COMPUTERNAME%" EQU "MOLLY-LAPTOP" ECHO Not Laptop
```

Or...

```
IF NOT "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="MOLLY-LAPTOP" ECHO Not Laptop
```

Comment: Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed the code formatting for you this time.